# How to only git push commits after a targeted commit?

Tags: git

```
commit hash101
Author: Me

    commit xxx

commit hash100
Merge: another hash
Author: Me

    merge

commit hash99
Merge: another hash
Author: Me

    commit xxx

commit hash98
Merge: another hash
Author: Me

    merge

...

commit hash1
Merge: another hash
Author: Me

    init
```

Let's say we have the above commits and I only want to push from commit hash100 since the code before is no longer needed - meaning I want 101 and 100 only, and I don't want commit 1 - 99 to be pushed to the remote, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you want `commit hash1` to **not** exist? Or do you just want the new changes to come after `commit hash2` and also have the changes of `commit hash1`?

Comment: For that you might need to do a `reverse commit` the `hash1`.

Comment: @mnestorov I modified the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you want to keep the changes from 1-99, or eliminate those changes? Interactive rebase handles both of those cases.

Comment: I would want to keep the changes from 1-99, but I also would want to know if I want to eliminate them what I might do.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the old commits by using the following command:

```
git revert hash1
```

[Here](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-revert-old-commit) is the reference for this command.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

If you don't want to see any of the commits you specified, then you can do a `git rebase` and squash everything into the two commits on top. This will leave your git tree only with two commits and the changes in those commits.

The good thing here is that you'll have a clear git history, just two commits. But you'll have to do a force push to update your remote and that might be messy if your working with other people.

The second thing you can do is to do a `git revert`. As the other answer already mentioned, this will create another set of commits that will undo all of your changes in the previous commits.

This will expand your git tree, but it will be clear what was happening in your project and it will be easier for others to get your changes.

Comment: I think the problem with `git revert` is that it will "undo" all of my changes in the previous commits, which is not ideal, I just want to make them invisible to people who pull from the remote - similar to if I create a brand new project and redo hash 100 - hash 101 and push them - but the difference is I would still be able to see hash 1 - hash 99 on my local project. This is done to keep my repos' sizes down.

Comment: @AeroWang In that case I think that an interactive rebase will do the job for you. If you want to keep 100 and 101, then just squash everything to them. It will look something like `git rebase -i HEAD~NUM_OF_COMMITS`.

Comment: It says `invalid upstream 'HEAD~NUM_OF_COMMITS'`.

Comment: Let's say if I have 2 commits, I do `HEAD~2` it says, `invalid upstream 'HEAD~NUM_OF_COMMITS'` and then if I do `HEAD~1`, nothing happens after entering a message...

Comment: `NUM_OF_COMMITS` is just a place holder. Let's say you have 5 commits. And for those 5 commits you want to squash them all the way to the root commit and be left with just two commits. You have to say `git rebase -i --root HEAD~5`. This will put you in an interactive rebase, you squash everything down to two commits and then you're done.

Comment: Check that you are on the tip of your branch and that you are specifying the right amount of commits.

Comment: I know `NUM_OF_COMMITS` is just a place holder. I tried 2 or 1 in my case. The problem being it only adds a new commit without doing anything to the old commits (or should it do precisely just that) and then if I push it doesn't hide the old commits either...

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Did you try with the `--root` option as well. You can also check [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for an example on squashing.